# Prove that some integral in $X \subset L^2$ is less then $\epsilon$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$X \subset L^2(a, b)$
X is precompact $\iff$
1. X bounded
2. $\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists \delta = \delta(\epsilon) > 0: \forall h\ |h| < \delta$
So, $\forall x \in X: \int_{a}^{b}|x(t + h) - x(t)|^2 dt  < \epsilon$
I need to prove this criterion.
I think, we may use Fourier series in order to reduce problem to $l^2$ space. Is this correct? If yes, how can i finish this proof?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @jabo thank you, I`ve updated question

Comment: This is a variant of the [Fréchet–Kolmogorov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet–Kolmogorov_theorem), you will find a proof in any function analysis book, cf. for example *Yosida*s book, chapter X.1.